# Let T be an infinite set and let A(T) be the group of permutations of T.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let T be an infinite set and let A(T) be the group of permutations of T.

Let M = { f ∈ A(T) | f(t) $\neq$ t for only a finite number of t ∈ T}.

Prove that M is a group.

What does f(t) = t mean in this problem?

Comment: To show that $M$ is a group, show that it is a subgroup of $A(T)$ using the "one-step" subgroup test.

Answer (score 1):

You can view each permutation of the set $T$ as a bijective function $f : T \to T$. If you're familiar with the notion of a symmetry group, this is much the same concept.

The symmetry group $S_n$ is essentially the set of permutations of the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$. We can envision these as mapping the set $\{1,...,n\}$ to itself, where $k \mapsto f(k)$ in the sense that $k$ goes to the position $f(k)$ in the permutation.

Explicitly, consider $S_4$, the set of permutations of $\{1,...,4\}$. Then we can define the permutation $4123$ by a function $f$ doing the mappings

$$1 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 3, 3 \mapsto 4, 4 \mapsto 1$$

because $1$ is in the second position, $2$ in the third, and so on, in the permutation. So instead of saying $(4123) \in S_4$ (to use the cycle notation for permutations), we can say $f \in S_4$ (where $f$ is defined by the above mapping).

You're dealing with an infinite set, $T$, not a finite set of integers, but the idea seems pretty similar. You can permute the elements of $T$ and define the permutation through some function. For example, you could define a permutation on $\Bbb Z$ by $f(n) = n+1$ for all integers $n$.

In this case, then,, the notion that $f(t)=t$ means $t$ is "fixed" for the permutation: it ends up in the same position as where it started. For example, a permutation on $\Bbb N$ could be defined by sending *every* element to itself, i.e. $f(t)=t$. Or you could define a permutation on $\Bbb R$ by $f(t)=t/2$, in which case the only $t$ such that $f(t)=t$ is $t=0$.

Similarly, $f(t) \ne t$ means each input is not sent to its original location (whenever the notion of "location" makes sense for $T$). If you're familiar with the notion of a derangement, the notion is similar.

Answer (score 0):

It means that permutation $f$ of $T$ fixes the element $t$ of $T$.  The term for $t$ is [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation).

For example, let $T$ be the positive integers, and define a permutation $f$ of $T$ by:
$$
f(1) = 2, \quad f(2) = 1, \quad f(t) = t \mbox{ for } t = 3, 4, \ldots .
$$
This permutation swaps 1 and 2, and fixes (leaves unmoved) all other elements of $T$.